# How to get the number of views for a page in ASP NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Im not asking for outside tools and plugins for this, i just need a simple solution to do this using asp.net.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3):

You need something that runs for every request, you can use an action filter and in the ActionExecuted method, get the request URL and increament the number of this URL.

You will have to have a table with the URL and PageViews initlaized to zero, on each request increment this PageViews variable.

Edit: Sample code below

1. Create a folder under your web project called Filters
2. Create a new class under this folder and name it `PageVisitCountFilter`, make it inherit from `ActionFilterAttribute`
3. Create a class under the Models folder to have the page visits data

   public class PageVisit
       {
           public string PageUrl { get; set; }
           public int Visits { get; set; }
       }
4. Add the following code to the `ActionFilterAttribute` class

   ```
   public class PageVisitCountFilter:ActionFilterAttribute
   {
   public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
   {
       base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);

       PageVisit page = new PageVisit();
       var repository = new PageVisitRepository();
       var pageUrl = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url;

       var page = repository.GetPageByUrl(pageUrl);
       if(page == null)
       {
           page = new PageVisit { PageUrl = pageUrl, Visits = 1 };
           repository.Save(page);
       }
       else
       {
           page.Visits++;
           repository.Update(page);
       }
   }
   }
   ```

The repository class is a class that add, updates and retrieves objects of type `PageVisit`

This way, you will have a table in the database with each page URL and its page visits

Comment: Any tutorials on how can i achieve this?

Comment: This is a link that explains action filters http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs 

let me know if you need more help

Comment: thanks for your help, but i went over that link read everything and i still dont see how it can help for my problem

Answer (score 0):

OK, if you need to get only unique views you can add a cookie, something like `Unique_User_Guid` and check in js if there are no cookie to send request by ajax, and in action - iterate and save current views count value.

If you need to check for all views, not unique - you can simply add simple codeto your action method, which will get current views value from db, iterate and save.