# How to Implement a View Count Feature for a Blog Website in Asp.net MVC Using a Database?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3

I have developed a blog website using the MVC pattern in Asp.net, and I'm looking to implement a view count feature for my blogs using a database. Specifically, I want to display the number of users who have visited each blog post and also render this count in the admin panel.

I have already created an admin panel, and my goal is to show the visit/view count below each blog post and within the admin panel. I initially attempted to use an API for this purpose, but it did not work as expected. Now, I'm considering using a database to store the visit/view count and fetch the data when needed.

Could someone provide guidance on how to achieve this? Any code examples, best practices, or step-by-step instructions on implementing a view count feature using a database in an Asp.net MVC application would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: See this link for help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39684704/how-to-get-the-number-of-views-for-a-page-in-asp-net-mvc-5

Answer (score 0):

On each blog page an action will be added that will increase the number of views loaded on the page. This action should be invoked to determine people's visits with each other.

```html
private void IncrementViewCount(int blogId)
{
    using (var context = new YourDbContext())
    {
        var blogView = context.BlogViews.FirstOrDefault(v => v.BlogId == blogId);

        if (blogView == null)
        {
            context.BlogViews.Add(new BlogView { BlogId = blogId, ViewCount = 1 });
        }
        else
        {
            blogView.ViewCount++;
        }
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```